# Filtering by multiple values of the same field

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have the following Model, ViewSet and FilterSet.

```py
class Contact(models.Model):
    PERSON = 'PERSON'
    ORGANIZATION = 'ORGANIZATION'
    COMPANY = 'COMPANY'
    TYPES = (
        (PERSON, 'Person'),
        (ORGANIZATION, 'Organization'),
        (COMPANY, 'Company'),
    )
    # irrelevant fields removed
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPES, null=True)
```

```py
class ContactViewSet(CustomViewSet):
    model = models.Contact
    read_serializer_class = serializers.ContactReadSerializer
    write_serializer_class = serializers.ContactWriteSerializer
    model_name = 'contact'
    filterset_class = filtersets.ContactFilterSet
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
```

```py
CONTACT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    'PERSON',
    'COMPANY',
    'ORGANIZATION'
)
class ContactFilterSet(FilterSet):
    # irrelevant fields removed
    type= CharFilter(
        choices=CONTACT_TYPE_CHOICES,
        field_name='type',
        lookup_expr='in'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = models.Contact
        fields = ('related_contacts', 'type', 'subtype', 'archived', 'legal_files', 'events', 'expenses', 'invoices', 'notes')
```

I want to filter Contacts by their type. For example, I want my query to respond with all Contacts where `type == 'PERSON' or 'COMPANY'` In theory, as I understood the [django-filter reference](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#multiplechoicefilter), I should be able to do so with a query like `/contacts?type=PERSON&type=COMPANY`. However, this returns the contacts matching the rightmost query (in this case `type=COMPANY`

What am I doing wrong? Am I using the wrong way to do it entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this instead?

```py
type = MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=CONTACT_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

`field_name='type'` is also unnecessary since it is the same as a filter field name.

Comment: And that would do it. Thank you!

Comment: @IraRamírez You're very welcome!